# Magento 2 - Auth.net Sandbox not working

Tags: magento2, authorize.net, sandbox-mode

Using Magento 2.2.4 - I have the Auth.net Direct Post payment method enabled, the Magento Auth.net patch applied, and with the configuration:

Gateway URL:

https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll

Transaction Details Url:

https://apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api

I'm seeing the transactions in the Auth.net sandbox `payment.log`:

`(TESTMODE) This transaction has been approved`

but an error is being thrown on the Magento side:

`Please enter a transaction ID to authorize this payment`

I've tried with Test Mode both enabled and disabled. How can I get this working properly?

Answer (score 0):

**Normally - Authorize.NET does not return a transaction ID in the test mode**

Please update with below file :`app/code/Magento/Authorizenet/Model/Directpost.php`

```
if (!$this->getResponse()->getXTransId()) { // approx line number 664
```

replace with

```
if (!$this->getResponse()->getXTestRequest() && !$this->getResponse()->getXTransId()) {
```

I hope its work for you.